# Automatically creating skeletons and proxies from java Interfaces on compile time

Tags: java, code-generation, classloader

I have a set of Interfaces, which are provided by other person. I need to generate Proxy and Skeleton classes for each of these interfaces either when starting application or when compiling (not sure which makes more sense).

I suppose that i need to do this:
I will get methods and arguments from provided Interfaces using reflection. Then, based on these data my Generator class will generate code of Proxies and Skeletons in form of .java files. After I have generated this code I need to compile it to .class files (using SystemJavaCompiler). And now I need to make these Proxy and Skeleton classes available to use throughout the application.

I am not sure about:
How do I make these classes part of the application, in the same way as all the classes that I wrote before running/compiling.

I have read something about writing my own ClassLoader , but i do not know if this is the right path to walk. I do not know what else to search google for.

So please write me In a few steps what to do and when, and what tools to use.

Answer (score 0):

1. If you need them for RMI, it's obsolete. No need for Proxy and Skeletons now, just use interfaces
2. if not, better generate *.java files to some `src\main\generated` folder before compilation (in Maven, there is a phase 'generate-sources') and let javac compile generated *.java files as regular classes.